# Decoding a picture from a gps tracker

Tags: image, hex, package, decode

I'am developing a server for a  GPS Tracker that can send pictures taken by a camera connected to it, inside a vehicle.

The problem is that I follow every step in the manual and I can't still decode the bytes sent by the tracker into a picture:

I receive the picture in packages separated by the headers and "tails", each one. When I receive the bytes I convert them into hexadecimals as the manual expecifies, then I have to remove the headers and "tails" and apparently after joinned the remain data and saved as a .jpeg, the image should appear, but it doesn't.

the company name is "Toplovo" from China. Have anyone else solve something similar?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; thanks for your post. Unfortunately, there is way too much random information here, and not enough description of what you have tried, and exactly what happens when you do.

Answer (score 0):

Are the line feeds part of your actual data?  Because if so I doubt that's supposed to happen.

Otherwise, make sure you're writing the file in binary mode.  In some languages this matters.  You didn't really specify, but make sure you're not in text mode.  Also make sure you're not using any datatypes unsuited for hexidecimal values (again, we don't even know what language you're using, so, it's kind of hard to give specific suggestions.)